# Adding an "Asking for unreasonable technical support" close reason?

Tags: feature-request, closing

Search didn't turn up any duplicates of this, so here goes...

Is it viable/reasonable to add a "Person is asking for unreasonable technical support" close option? I've seen several instances where people are asking for "Help I can't login to Minecraft" due to password issues, or most recently [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/whenever-i-load-up-my-world-it-crashes) where they have a modded Minecraft world that crashes. None of the close reasons seem blatantly obvious to me, of course if there is one I should be using for this, I'll start using that one.

The current options are:

- duplicate of
- off topic because
- unclear what you're asking
- too broad
- primarily opinion based

The "off topic" option mentions "not about video games", although "too broad" could possibly fit, but again none of these seem like a great reason. 
Technical support is rarely "opinion based", nor issues like this are likely exact duplicates. (And if they were, they would likely be duplicates of an already-closed question for the same reasons.)

It could potentially give some "things to try before you post that kind of question" suggestions to those people who don't realize they should (for example) disable all mods to see if that's causing their crash.

**Edit**: Poking around a bit more, I've seen some comments saying that it's difficult to add close reasons. If that's the case and none will be added, I'd suggest rewording at least one of them so that it's more of a catch-all, and could use the comments to explain the actual reason for the closing votes.

Comment: We're kind of in the process of getting a close reason specifically for modded Minecraft, or...something. I'm actually not entirely sure the status. Let me check with people who know more about it. But the point is that it's pretty much *just* modded Minecraft that we've decided to ban. Unfortunately, other technical support questions are still admissible.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it. Definitely modded Minecraft are the vast majority of the types I'm seeing -- that's also why I added "unreasonable"... I know regular/general/etc tech support questions are welcome here... either way, glad to hear that's coming! Thanks for the update.

Comment: To clarify Strix's point: Technical Support for Modded Minecraft is the only area of tech support that we have a problem with, you can [read why here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/10391/28182). Also in the discussions on that answer, the point is raised that perhaps all tech support should be disallowed, however as SevenSidedDie mentions: we shouldn't ban the whole lot of them just because one subtopic is causing problems. [Discussed from here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10390/minecraft-crash-questions-should-be-made-off-topic-yes-no/10391#comment30924_10391)

Comment: Fair enough. Should I delete this question then, or is there value in leaving it here?